# How a collision for a function can be for another one

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

We have two bit strings  $x\in\{0,1\}^q$ , $y\in\{0,1\}^w$ of length $q$ bits, and $w$ bits.  The notation $x\mathbin\|y$ means $(q+w)$ bits long concatenation,

And the functions: $H∶\ \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^n$
and $F∶\ \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{n+6}$ defined in terms of $H$ as
$$F(x) = 000\mathbin\|H(1\mathbin\|x)\mathbin\|111$$

How can a collision $(x_1, x_2)$ for $F$ be turned into a collision for $H$ ?

Can any one please explain why, is it because $F$ has also $H(1\|x)$ in it and $F$ implies $H$ ? Or are any collision for $F$ will be a collision for $H$ also ?

Comment: Please tell us what ideas you have considered so far.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116577/discussion-on-question-by-mr-c-how-a-collision-for-a-function-can-be-for-anothe).

Comment: @fgrieu: looks like math mode doesn't work in chat :-/

Comment: @cisnjxqu : Yes, known limitation. That's something for [crypto-meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/), or the general [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), or the [side channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/784/the-side-channel), but not for comment. These two might eventually vanish.